# How to do if lineInfo not equals to multiple strings in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

On the second if statement, I want to do lineInfo not equals to multiple strings, then return ....

```
if (lineInfo.Equals("Eriri")) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Here is Eriri"); Eriri.Visible = true; 
}

if (!lineInfo.Equals("Emilia", "Eriri", "Xayah", "Eucliwood", "Asuna"))
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, we do not have her, try another one");
    Waifus.Visible = true;
}
```

The first one works because I only have one string. The second one gives an error on .equals. Says "No overload for methods 'Equals.' takes 5 arguments".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

string [Equals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads) method can only compare one string value.

```
public override bool Equals(object obj);
```

If you want to compare multiple strings, you can try to use collection [Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1.contains?view=netframework-4.7.2) method to make it.

Add you want to compare string value in, string array or collection.

then use `Contains` to check the value, whether in collection to do compare multiple strings.

```
List<string> condition = new List<string>() { "Emilia", "Eriri", "Xayah" , "Eucliwood" };
if (!condition.Contains(lineInfo))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, we do not have her, try another one");
    Waifus.Visible = true;
}
```

And if you do this in multiple places, here is an extension method that you can use:

```
public static bool EqualsOneOf(this string self, params string[] values) => values.Contains(self);
```

Usage:
    lineInfo.EqualsOneOf("Emilia", "Eriri", "Xayah", "Eucliwood", "Asuna")